# Is it possible to transparently forward requests from IIS7 to Apache2?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, apache-2.2, arr

I have Windows Server 2008 server and IIS 7.0 being running on port 80 (main web server). Also I have Apache 2.2 running on port 8081 (for SVN).

Is it possible to configure IIS that way so it will transparently forward/proxy requests to http://svn.example.com:80 to http://svn.example.com:8081

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. This is called a "Reverse Proxy". See the following question for another solution (apparently it can be troublesome, but see Scott's answer):

[Using IIS7 as a Reverse Proxy](https://serverfault.com/questions/55309/using-iis7-as-a-reverse-proxy)

You can also use [ISAPI ReWrite for doing this](http://www.helicontech.com/), it seems to be a bit of a defacto standard for IIS, and uses a .htaccess compatible file format.

Comment: That question's answer is to run apache on port 80. This is not what I'm looking for. But I will check out ISAPI ReWrite you mentioned

Comment: @abat, check Scott's answer as I mentioned. He gives more detail on how to do it. The only reason it's not the accepted answer was because it came too late.

Comment: Sorry, have read your answer inattentively. Already took a look to ARR. Thanks!